# React: why can't I add a custom styling class to my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've made a simple component:

```
const CloseButton = ({ onClick }: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <CloseIcon className={classes.closeButtonStyles} onClick={onClick} />;
};

export default CloseButton;
```

Which I can call like:

```
<CloseButton onClick={handleClose} />
```

This works fine.

But when I add a `className` attribute, eg:

```
<CloseButton className={classes.closeButton} onClick={handleClose} />
```

I get the error:

> Type '{ className: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable
>   to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { onClick: (event: MouseEvent) => void; }'.   Property 'className' does not exist on
>   type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { onClick: (event: MouseEvent) => void; }'

Why does this appear? Why is the `className` attribute getting mixed up with the `onClick` prop?

Comment: your CloseButton component doesn't accept `className` as a prop, you are assigning the classes using `useStyles `

Comment: How is `CloseIcon` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how is the `CloseIcon` component defined, but I am guessing that there is some kind of mismatch of props typings.

Do make sure that the type aliases/interfaces for `CloseIcon` includes the `className` props (on top of the `onClick` method props):

```
interface CloseIconProps {
  className: string;
  onClick: () => void;
}
```

(You can also choose to define `className` as an optional field)

Answer (score -2):

Typescript does not know that the function is a React component.

You might try adding adding the React type to the component, e.g. instead of `const CloseButton =`, you would use `const CloseButton: React.FC<{yourPropsHere: string}> =`